# How to get a subset of columns based on row values in Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe in Spark (it has only one row):

```
df.show
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|4.4|  2|  3|  7|2.6|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I want to get the columns that their values are greater than 2.8 (just as an example). The outcomes should be:

```
List(B, D , E)
```

Here is my own solution:

```
val cols = df.columns
val threshold = 2.8
val values = df.rdd.collect.toList
val res = values
         .flatMap(x => x.toSeq)
         .map(x => x.toString.toDouble)
         .zip(cols)
         .filter(x => x._1 > threshold)
         .map(x => x._2)
```

Comment: What is the issue with the solution. Do you need any other solution without using rdd

Comment: The collect part slows down the code a lot. Beside this, I think the final solution should be much simpler than this.

Comment: Ok sure let me check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `udf` function should give you correct result as

```
val columns = df.columns

def getColumns = udf((cols: Seq[Double]) => cols.zip(columns).filter(_._1 > 2.8).map(_._2))

df.withColumn("columns > 2.8", getColumns(array(columns.map(col(_)): _*))).show(false)
```

So that even if you have multiple rows as below

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|A  |B  |C  |D  |E  |F  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|1  |4.4|2  |3  |7  |2.6|
|4  |2.7|2  |3  |1  |2.9|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You will get result for each rows as

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------------+
|A  |B  |C  |D  |E  |F  |columns > 2.8|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------------+
|1  |4.4|2  |3  |7  |2.6|[B, D, E]    |
|4  |2.7|2  |3  |1  |2.9|[A, D, F]    |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 2):

you could use `explode` and `array` functions:

```
df.select(
    explode(
      array(
        df.columns.map(c => struct(lit(c).alias("key"), col(c).alias("val"))): _*
      )
    ).as("kv")
  )
  .where($"kv.val" > 2.8)
  .select($"kv.key")
  .show()

+---+
|key|
+---+
|  B|
|  D|
|  E|
+---+
```

you could then collect this result. But I don't see any issue with collecting the dataframe first as t has only 1 row:

```
df.columns.zip(df.first().toSeq.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double]))
      .collect{case (c,v) if v>2.8 => c} // Array(B,D,E)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val c = df.columns.foldLeft(df){(a,b) =>  a.withColumn(b, when(col(b) > 2.8, b))}
c.collect
```

You can remove the nulls from the array